# Logic to exit application if it cannot get websocket connection

Tags: c, loops, websocket, logic, exit

I have a c program that uses `libwebsockets` to open a websocket from the client to a server. However, sometimes the network can be down. In such cases, I wrote some logic below that trying to connect 10 times and if it unsuccessful then it should exit the application. The logic works as expected but it doesn't seem very neat and I'm sure there is a better way of doing it. I'd appreciate comments on how I could code this logic better. Also is `exit(-1)` the correct way to exit?

```
//Try connect to websocket 10 times or else exit app
 for (int j =0; j < 10; j++) {

         web_socket = lws_client_connect_via_info ( &ccinfo);

          //If you get a connection then exit the for loop
          if(web_socket){
                 break;
          }

      }

   //If you tried 10 times web_socket will be NULL so exit the application
      if(!web_socket) {
          exit(-1);
      }
```

Comment: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` is more descriptive and more portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[exit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) from `stdlib.h` is the best approach. From standard

> Terminates the process normally, performing the regular cleanup for
>   terminating processes.
>
> First, all functions registered by calls to atexit are executed in the
>   reverse order of their registration. Then, all streams are closed and
>   the temporary files deleted, and finally the control is returned to
>   the host environment.
>
> The status argument is returned to the host environment.

I think that code logic is simple and understandable for everyone.

*"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."* - Donald E. Knuth